# Python crashing when I'm running the program with a custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Whenever I run this code, Python stops working. To make sure that this isn't my system's issue, I tried running it in Google Colab, which crashed too. The crash happens when the execution reached `model.fit` line

```
data = load_iris()
X = data['data']
y = data['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.33, random_state =23)

def energy(x):
    val,vec = tf.linalg.eigh(x)
    en = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(val))
    return en

def energy_loss(y_actual,y_predicted):
    mtm_actual = tf.linalg.matmul(y_actual,tf.transpose(y_actual))
    ptp_actual = tf.linalg.matmul(y_predicted,tf.transpose(y_predicted))
    actual_energy = energy(y_actual)
    predicted_energy = energy(y_predicted)
    return tf.math.abs(actual_energy - predicted_energy)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,input_dim=4))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3,activation='relu'))
opt = Adam(lr = 1)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss=energy_loss,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train,X_train,epochs=25,verbose = 1,batch_size = 5)
```

I am using tensorflow 1.15.0 when running this code. Any ideas what is causing this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the energy function where you calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

```
tf.linalg.eigh
```

> Computes the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the innermost N-by-N
>   matrices in tensor such that tensor[...,:,:] * v[..., :,i] = e[..., i]
>   * v[...,:,i], for i=0...N-1.

This is from official docs. Your input to the energy function does not satisfy these conditions.

The issue can be fixed by passing the correct parameters to the `energy` function

```
def energy_loss(y_actual,y_predicted):
    mtm_actual = tf.linalg.matmul(y_actual,tf.transpose(y_actual))
    ptp_actual = tf.linalg.matmul(y_predicted,tf.transpose(y_predicted))
    actual_energy = energy(mtm_actual)
    predicted_energy = energy(ptp_actual)
    return tf.math.abs(actual_energy - predicted_energy)
```

Comment: The reason I used `X_train` twice is that I'm attempting to do an unsupervised learning